# Xpages - How to prevent users from creating a new document if one already exists

Tags: xpages

I'm working on a Notes database. I want to prevent a user from creating a new document if there already exists a completed document from/by the user. In Notes classic form, I have incorporated that check in the QueryOpen event (see code below) and it works well.  How can I have a similar event in xpages? Thanks a lot
Anthony

```
If isnewdoc Then
  mkey = Evaluate("@Name([CN]; @UserName)")
  Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
  Set view = db.GetView("view-name")
  view.AutoUpdate = False
  Set ve = view.GetEntryByKey(mkey)
  If Not (ve Is Nothing) Then
     Messagebox "Please note that you already have a document"
     Continue = False
  Else
     Continue = True
  End If
Else
  Continue = True
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

sessionScope allows you to store information relevant to the current browser session (often used to capture user-specific information). Many apps tend to use something along the lines of an initUser() function - look at http://xhelp.openntf.org, for example, which has initCurrUser() in application SSJS library.

With that kind of approach, you could run your check when the user first hits any page in the application, by calling the function in the beforePageLoad event. You can store the result in a sessionScope variable. Then you know for the life of the browser session whether the user has created a document or not. You can hide the create button or prevent access to the page or whatever based on that sessionScope variable.

When they create the document during that session, just remember to set the sessionScope variable.

This is even better practice than the queryOpen event of the Form, because instead of running everytime they create or open a document, this just runs once per session.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event on the data source called querySaveDocument. In this event if you return false than the document won't save.

Not sure what you want to do but you could at that point get the existing document for the user and then update any values the user changed.

Or, you could put some logic in the beforePageLoad event that sees if that user created a document already and if so, load that document. If not, then create a new document. The beforePageLoad event could set the document unid to open in a viewScope variable and then pull that information into the document data source settings.

Howard